# How to stop Vim from sourcing a file halfway through?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I'm mostly a Neovim user and I would like to share part of my config with regular Vim. Here's the problem: my `init.vim` is organized in such a way that at the top there are the general Vim options, custom mappings and things that don't depend on any plugin being installed. At the bottom there's the usual `vim-plug` block plus all the options as they related to specific plugins.

What I would like to do is to symlink my `~/.vimrc` to my `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` and have something like this in my `init.vim`:

```
" General options

if !has('nvim')
    " Stop sourcing here if regular vim is sourcing this file
endif

" Plugins options
```

When I open Vim, I usually don't need my plugins but I would still like to keep my settings, mappings and whatnot. However, I'm having a hard time finding which instruction I should use instead of that comment.

I tried using `return` but I got an error during startup saying that the keyword can be used only inside of functions. I also tried using `exit` but that causes Vim to close itself right away.

Is there any way to achieve this?

P.S. I know I could use

```
if has('nvim')
   " Plugins options
endif
```

but the plugins section spans several lines and I just think the other way is cleaner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command is called `finish`. So it's pretty trivial

```
if !has('nvim')
    " Stop sourcing here if regular vim is sourcing this file
    finish
endif
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!